# how to loop through array of objects and check if a value in that object matches an item in another array using lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of items which are featured components like this:

```
var featuredIds = ['footerB', 'headerA', 'landingA'];
```

I also have an array of objects that looks something like this:

```
[{
    "title": "first footer",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "footer",
    "uId": "footerA"
  },{
    "title": "second footer",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "footer",
    "uId": "footerB"
  },
  {
    "title": "first header",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "header",
    "uId": "headerA"
  },
  {
    "title": "first header",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "header",
    "uId": "headerB"
  },
  {
    "title": "first landing",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "landing",
    "uId": "landingA"
  },
  {
    "title": "second landing",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "landing",
    "uId": "landingB"
  },
  {
    "title": "third landing",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "landing",
    "uId": "landingC"
  },
  {
    "title": "first nav",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "navigation",
    "uId": "navA"
  },{
    "title": "first footer",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "blog",
      "uId": "blogA"
  },
  {
    "title": "second footer",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "blog",
    "uId": "blogB"
  },
  {
    "title": "first header",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "contact_button",
    "uId": "contact_buttonA"
  },
  {
    "title": "first landing",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "content_bloc",
    "uId": "content_blocA"
  },
  {
    "title": "second landing",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "content_bloc",
    "uId": "content_blocB"
  },
  {
    "title": "third landing",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "content_bloc",
    "uId": "content_blocC"
  },
  {
    "title": "first nav",
    "section": "components",
    "categoryId": "cover",
    "uId": "coverA"
  }]
```

I want to create a new array which only holds the components that match the featureIds I provide in the array of `featureIds` which would look like this:

```
[{
    "title": "second footer",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "footer",
    "uId": "footerB"
  },{
    "title": "first header",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "header",
    "uId": "headerA"
  },
  {
    "title": "first landing",
    "section": "structure",
    "categoryId": "landing",
    "uId": "landingA"
  }]
```

I have looked at using _.some, _.find and a few others but haven't been able to get the result I am looking for. I have written this already using a double for loop which is why I want to us lodash to cut that out/learn something new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lodash's chain with `_.keyBy()` and `_.at()`:

```js
function filterBy(arr, filters) {
  return _(features)
  .keyBy('uId')
  .at(filters)
  .value();
}

var features = [{
  "title": "first footer",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "footer",
  "uId": "footerA"
}, {
  "title": "second footer",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "footer",
  "uId": "footerB"
}, {
  "title": "first header",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "header",
  "uId": "headerA"
}, {
  "title": "first header",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "header",
  "uId": "headerB"
}, {
  "title": "first landing",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "landing",
  "uId": "landingA"
}, {
  "title": "second landing",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "landing",
  "uId": "landingB"
}, {
  "title": "third landing",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "landing",
  "uId": "landingC"
}, {
  "title": "first nav",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "navigation",
  "uId": "navA"
}, {
  "title": "first footer",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "blog",
  "uId": "blogA"
}, {
  "title": "second footer",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "blog",
  "uId": "blogB"
}, {
  "title": "first header",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "contact_button",
  "uId": "contact_buttonA"
}, {
  "title": "first landing",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "content_bloc",
  "uId": "content_blocA"
}, {
  "title": "second landing",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "content_bloc",
  "uId": "content_blocB"
}, {
  "title": "third landing",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "content_bloc",
  "uId": "content_blocC"
}, {
  "title": "first nav",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "cover",
  "uId": "coverA"
}];

var featuredIds = ['footerB', 'headerA', 'landingA'];

var result = filterBy(features, featuredIds);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you can use ES6, a combination of `Array.prototype.filter()` and `Set`:

```js
const filterBy = (arr, filters) => {
  const filtersSet = new Set(filters);
  
  return arr.filter((item) => filtersSet.has(item.uId));
};

const featuredIds = ['footerB', 'headerA', 'landingA'];

const features = [{
  "title": "first footer",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "footer",
  "uId": "footerA"
}, {
  "title": "second footer",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "footer",
  "uId": "footerB"
}, {
  "title": "first header",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "header",
  "uId": "headerA"
}, {
  "title": "first header",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "header",
  "uId": "headerB"
}, {
  "title": "first landing",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "landing",
  "uId": "landingA"
}, {
  "title": "second landing",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "landing",
  "uId": "landingB"
}, {
  "title": "third landing",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "landing",
  "uId": "landingC"
}, {
  "title": "first nav",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "navigation",
  "uId": "navA"
}, {
  "title": "first footer",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "blog",
  "uId": "blogA"
}, {
  "title": "second footer",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "blog",
  "uId": "blogB"
}, {
  "title": "first header",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "contact_button",
  "uId": "contact_buttonA"
}, {
  "title": "first landing",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "content_bloc",
  "uId": "content_blocA"
}, {
  "title": "second landing",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "content_bloc",
  "uId": "content_blocB"
}, {
  "title": "third landing",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "content_bloc",
  "uId": "content_blocC"
}, {
  "title": "first nav",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "cover",
  "uId": "coverA"
}];

const result = filterBy(features, featuredIds);

console.log(result);
```

Another lodash option is `_.intersectionWith()`:

```js
function filterBy(arr, filters) {
  return _.intersectionWith(arr, filters, function(value, filter) {
    return value.uId === filter;
  });
}

var features = [{
  "title": "first footer",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "footer",
  "uId": "footerA"
}, {
  "title": "second footer",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "footer",
  "uId": "footerB"
}, {
  "title": "first header",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "header",
  "uId": "headerA"
}, {
  "title": "first header",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "header",
  "uId": "headerB"
}, {
  "title": "first landing",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "landing",
  "uId": "landingA"
}, {
  "title": "second landing",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "landing",
  "uId": "landingB"
}, {
  "title": "third landing",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "landing",
  "uId": "landingC"
}, {
  "title": "first nav",
  "section": "structure",
  "categoryId": "navigation",
  "uId": "navA"
}, {
  "title": "first footer",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "blog",
  "uId": "blogA"
}, {
  "title": "second footer",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "blog",
  "uId": "blogB"
}, {
  "title": "first header",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "contact_button",
  "uId": "contact_buttonA"
}, {
  "title": "first landing",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "content_bloc",
  "uId": "content_blocA"
}, {
  "title": "second landing",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "content_bloc",
  "uId": "content_blocB"
}, {
  "title": "third landing",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "content_bloc",
  "uId": "content_blocC"
}, {
  "title": "first nav",
  "section": "components",
  "categoryId": "cover",
  "uId": "coverA"
}];

var featuredIds = ['footerB', 'headerA', 'landingA'];

var result = filterBy(features, featuredIds);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.6/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what is your opinion of the best function to use? _.intersectionBy or the current one in the answer?

I am trying to work out the if typeof part as it seems strange to me as you return item as well. i guess its something under the hood in lodash that gets the right object

Comment: The `_.keyBy` method is more clean. The `_.intersection()` was an idea, but I've decided it's a bit hackish. Because we intersect the two arrays, an items can be a feature object or string, so I need to extract the value to intersect with.

Comment: Thank you for that and thank you for explaining. It didnt quite sit right with me and wasn't quite sure why but now you say its hackish, it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. I've added another option using `_.intersectionWith()`, which is nicer then the one with the `_.intersectionBy()`.

Comment: thanks for adding another option. I quite like intersectionWith(). it reads better than the key chaining one i feel

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `filter()` and `includes()` in plain js.

```js
var data = [{"title":"first footer","section":"structure","categoryId":"footer","uId":"footerA"},{"title":"second footer","section":"structure","categoryId":"footer","uId":"footerB"},{"title":"first header","section":"structure","categoryId":"header","uId":"headerA"},{"title":"first header","section":"structure","categoryId":"header","uId":"headerB"},{"title":"first landing","section":"structure","categoryId":"landing","uId":"landingA"},{"title":"second landing","section":"structure","categoryId":"landing","uId":"landingB"},{"title":"third landing","section":"structure","categoryId":"landing","uId":"landingC"},{"title":"first nav","section":"structure","categoryId":"navigation","uId":"navA"},{"title":"first footer","section":"components","categoryId":"blog","uId":"blogA"},{"title":"second footer","section":"components","categoryId":"blog","uId":"blogB"},{"title":"first header","section":"components","categoryId":"contact_button","uId":"contact_buttonA"},{"title":"first landing","section":"components","categoryId":"content_bloc","uId":"content_blocA"},{"title":"second landing","section":"components","categoryId":"content_bloc","uId":"content_blocB"},{"title":"third landing","section":"components","categoryId":"content_bloc","uId":"content_blocC"},{"title":"first nav","section":"components","categoryId":"cover","uId":"coverA"}];
var featuredIds = ['footerB', 'headerA', 'landingA'];

var result = data.filter(function(e) {
  return featuredIds.includes(e.uId);
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank you! for your help

Comment: Note that `includes()` is ES6 you can also use `indexOf()` instead like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1302/